# Why is my Meteor UserId not displaying with this code?

Tags: html, spacebars, meteor-accounts, meteor-helper, isomorphic-javascript

I want to (out of curiosity) see my userId while I experiment with my Meteor app. I am trying to display it this way:

HTML:

```
<body>
. . .
<div class="container">
   {{> userIdTemplate}}
   {{> postTravelWizard}}
</div>

</body>

<template name="userIdTemplate">
  {{getUserId}}
</template>
```

Javascript:

```
Template.userIdTemplate.helpers({
     getUserId: function () {
       return Meteor.userId;
     }
   });
```

Stepping through the .js in CDT, I see that the value of Meteor.userId is "undefined." I am not authenticated - just runnign the app with the insecure package still installed. Is that why userId is undefined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until you login, Meteor.userId() and Meteor.user() will both return `null`, per the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_user). Also, your code has a typo, `Meteor.userId`. should be `Meteor.userId()` (note the function call).